# Insert em duas tabelas distintas

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho duas tabelas (`cliente` e `telefone`), preciso inserir o nome na tabela `cliente` e o telefone do cliente na tabela `telefone`, ao mesmo tempo, pelo mesmo formulário.

No formulário HTML eu consegui colocar todos os campos (nome, ddd, telefone) mas não consigo enviar para as duas tabelas.

```php
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
    $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'nome',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $ddd = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'ddd',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $telefone = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'telefone',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    

    $solicita = "INSERT INTO `cliente` (`nome`) VALUES ($nome),
                 INSERT INTO `telefone` (`ddd`,`telefone`) VALUES ($ddd,$telefone)";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$solicita);

    if($linha_usuario = mysqli_insert_id($conn)){  
    echo "Cadastrado com sucesso";
    }else{
        echo "Erro ao cadastrar";
    }
}
?>
```

---

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Desafio Estágio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Cadastro de clientes</h1>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="form">
        <label for="nome">Nome</label>
        <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome">
        <label for="ddd">D.D.D</label>
        <input type="text" id="ddd" name="ddd" size="2">
        <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
        <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone">
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" id="cadastrar">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: Diagrama de classe]

Comment: Bom dia, por favor, adicione o código com o que você tentou fazer o envio para poder ajuda-lo

Comment: Olá Osiris coloquei o código, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Aparece algum erro ou simplesmente não insere?

Comment: Não cadastra no banco de geito nenhum, eu tentei colocando somente o nome na tabela cliente e deu certo mas quando tento cadastrar na outra tabela não vai. Em nenhuma tabela

Comment: Olá!
Você pode solucionar executando as queries uma a uma.
Ou pode tentar usar o [mysqli.multi-query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score -1):

acredito que o erro acontece porque o campo FK do cliente na tabela telefone não está no teu segundo insert, está faltando campos. Divide os 2 inserts e antes de inserir o telefone tente fazer o que fiz abaixo.

```
$sql = select * from cliente where like '%$nome%';
$consulta = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

$id = $linha['id'];
}

if($id == TRUE) {

$sqlTelefone = 'insert into telefone (cliente_id, ddd, telefone) values ($id,$ddd,$telefone)';
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlTelefone);

}
```

cara, eu fiz de cabeça, pode ter erro de síntaxe, mas qualquer coisa deixa um comentário.
Abraço!